# Wix keeps looking in the wrong folder

Tags: xml, wix, filepath

I am trying to build an installer using WIX. However, for a large majority of my files wix keeps looking into my debug folder for all of the files instead of looking into the correct folder.

The files are in Core\Media\Sub1

and it keeps looking into Core\bin\Release\Media\Sub1

They are mostly png, wmv, and dll files

here is the way I declared the locations:

```
<?define Core_TargetDir=$(var.Core.TargetDir)?>
```

and then the files

```
<ComponentGroup Id = "Sub1_Files" Directory = "Sub1" /> 
    <Component Id="Picture.png" Guid="e4b5bca3-fb31-4e16-91f3-b77fabd1aae1">
            <File Id="Picture.png" Name="PicName.png" Source="$(var.Core_TargetDir)Media\Sub1\CheckedNormal.png" />
```

How do I get this to look into the correct Folder?

I would just move these files to the bin folders, but due to the size of the project, I'm not sure I will be able find all of the references. Plus most of the files are found in the bin. It's just 20ish files that are giving me problems...

Comment: You need to verify that, for the release build, the installer project isn't set to the debug build.  Yes, it can happen.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations Open the config manager and make sure the project is set to release.

Comment: @Will The project is set to release, but that doesn't change the fact that that the files I am looking at aren't in bin, but in a higher folder.
There are lots of files that are in the folder (This is a very large project, we had a team of 10 working on it before) so I can't just move the files somewhere else either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
<?define Core_ProjectDir=$(var.Core.ProjectDir)?>
```

Right after, or right before:

```
<?define Core_TargetDir=$(var.Core.TargetDir)?>
```

Then change the code segment that says

```
<ComponentGroup Id = "Sub1_Files" Directory = "Sub1" /> 
    <Component Id="Picture.png" Guid="e4b5bca3-fb31-4e16-91f3-b77fabd1aae1">
            <File Id="Picture.png" Name="PicName.png" Source="$(var.Core_TargetDir)Media\Sub1\CheckedNormal.png" />
```

To

```
<ComponentGroup Id = "Sub1_Files" Directory = "Sub1" /> 
    <Component Id="Picture.png" Guid="e4b5bca3-fb31-4e16-91f3-b77fabd1aae1">
            <File Id="Picture.png" Name="PicName.png" Source="$(var.Core_ProjectDir)Media\Sub1\CheckedNormal.png" />
```

This TargetDir always looks in the debug folder of your project, and ProjectDir always looks in the project folder itself. For more info on different file paths you can take with Wix, look at the [Project Reference Guide](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html).